# How to install PIL or Pillow via MobaXTerm on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How do I install PIL or Pillow in Python 3.4.5 on Windows with MobaXTerm?

I already tried the `python3 -m pip install Pillow` workaround as well as just `python3 -m pip install PIL` and I get an error message saying `/bin/python3: No module named pip.`

Am I just entering the commands wrong or is there something more I have to do to install these libraries on Windows with MobaXTerm?

**EDIT: I got pip working, but it won't install Pillow or PIL.**

For PIL it gives me :

```
Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

And for Pillow it gives me this wall of text:

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-4.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Pillow)
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pillow ... error
  Complete output from command /bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpg30o2jx1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  Single threaded build for windows
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 779, in <module>
      zip_safe=not debug_build(), )
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 549, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qn77j4nh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Single threaded build for windows
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.6.0-i686-3.4/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 779, in <module>
        zip_safe=not debug_build(), )
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 549, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------
Command "/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qn77j4nh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xetzsf44/Pillow/
```

What's the problem here? It does the same for both with easy_install also.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't bother with the unmaintained PIL, use the maintained Pillow fork.

Second, what's happening for "pip install pillow" is it's downloading the source zip and trying to build from source, which involves compiling C codd. Whilst this is fairly easy on Linux and Mac, it's a big pain to set up the compiler for Windows.

However, Pillow is also released as precompiled binaries, called "wheels". Normally pip and Windows will install from wheel, and I know it works on the bogstandard cmd.exe, but looks like pip/MobaXTerm is having trouble.

So instead download a Windows wheel file directly from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/ (cp34 is Python 3.4) and run "pip install name.whl".